# bash: /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zip, tar, rm

I have too many files in a folder. I just want my inodes to be get free as soon as possible,So I have tried with

```
find ./EcoBackup/* -name '*.*' > FilesBackupName.txt
bash: /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long
tar -cv -T FilesBackupName.txt -f tarball.tar
```

How can i speed up my tar without fail with argument list is too long ?

Will it work without fail ?

```
find /foot/bar/ -name '*.*' -exec mv -t tarball.tar {} +

find /foot/bar/ -name '*.*' -print0 | xargs -0 tar -t tarball.tar
```

Can i remove the file at the same type ?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this happens is that bash actually expands the asterisk to every matching file, producing too many arguments in the command line. So after removing it, it should be fine (e.g. [here](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/))

```
find ./EcoBackup/ -name '*.*' > FilesBackupName.txt
```

and your suggested solutions should also work.

---

You can use the option `--remove-files` to remove files in one go with `tar` command

```
tar --remove-files -cv -T FilesBackupName.txt -f tarball.tar
```